# How to change media file upload date in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, date, media

I am redesigning a website and both are based on WordPress. This is basically a Podcasts website. I am having an issue which is media files upload date in the new website. File Uploading date for Media files on the previous website is different than in the newly created one. I need the same date as of the previous site but I am not being able to do it. I will really appreciate any help, please.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask]. This question as-is is too broad.

Comment: can you specify the migration procedure you took `old-site --> new-site` ? if you have migrated with FTP - mysql import the dates should be the same. if you done it manually you can still fix it .

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is to create a post with the same date as the folder you want to upload the image to. Then upload the image from within that post. WP will put it in the matching year/month folder.

https://organicweb.com.au/wordpress/image-wrong-date/